# How to superscript and subscript string value Dynamicall in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public partial class SupperSub : Window
{
    Control _txtbox;
    Control _bt;
    public SupperSub()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();         
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         _txtbox = (Control)sender;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         _bt = (Control)sender;
         TextBox CastingTxt = _txtbox as TextBox;
         Button CastingBtn = _bt as Button;

         var Index = CastingTxt.CaretIndex;
         CastingTxt.Text = CastingTxt.Text.Insert(Index,CastingBtn.Content.ToString());
         CastingTxt.Focus();
         CastingTxt.CaretIndex = Index +1;
    }
}
```

It's result will be like this
[image]

What i need is, If i click button 2.It's content(2) should be **superscript of 5**(textbox value).
if i click button 3,It's content(3) should be **subscript of 5** textbox value.What i have to do to get the result what i need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) control.

Then take a look at this [example](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/11/05/wpf-richtextbox-subscript-and-superscript-without-font-restrictions/).